# Ria Entity Model: Join Entity to Self NOT on Primary Key

Tags: wcf, silverlight, entity-framework, ria

I have a table `Document` that looks like this:

```
DocumentID(PK) | DocumentKey | RelatedDocument | .....
--------------------------------------------------------
1              | AR_123      | NULL            | .....
2              | AR_234_C0   | C0              | .....
3              | AP_123      | NULL            | .....
4              | AP_234_C0   | C0              | .....
5              | USPS_123_C0 | C0              | .....
6              | USPS_234    | NULL            | .....
```

I cannot change how this is set up.

`RelatedDocument` has a value that is neither the `DocumentID` nor `DocumentKey`.  But all `Documents` that share a `Related` are `Related`.

Is it posisible to set up the Model so that when a document is pulled in, it will have a list of `RelatedDocuments`?

For example, Document 1 would have Key = AR123, and no related, whereas Document 2 would have Key = AR_234_C0 and a set of related docs containing documents with IDs 2,4,5...

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a linq-to-entities query, let me know if you are looking for something else

```
var query = from d in context.Documents
            join d2 in context.Documents on d.RelatedDocument equals d2.RelatedDocument into dg
            select new
            {
              Document = d,
              RelatedDocuments = dg,
            };
```

Comment: The issue I have with that is that I would not be able to pull that in using the standard RIA stuff (i.e. DomainDataSource).  That is why I am hoping to somehow add a property (EntityCollection<Document> RelatedDocuments) to Document that would hold the related documents... Perhaps I am being to greedy in wanting this to work with DomainDataSource?